# ftp_put works fine, but ftp_get returns nothing

Tags: php, ftp

I have a generic FTP connection that connects fine

```
$server = "ftp.********";
$user = "*********";
$pass = "********";
$connect = ftp_connect($server) or die("Couldn't connect"); 

$login = ftp_login($connect, $user, $pass) or die("Error");  
ftp_pasv($connect, true);
```

When I run
`ftp_put($connect, "test.php", "test.php", FTP_BINARY);` everything works fine, but going back the other way with `ftp_get($connect, "test.php", "test.php", FTP_BINARY);` it just doesn't run.

The files have 777 permissions, so does my local folder (for testing purposes).

Comment: is the return value from ftp_get() false?

Comment: Is `test.php` the script itself? Because if it's running it's being used, if it's being used it cannot be modified.

Comment: I thought for sure I set everything I needed to to '777' permissions. But I created another folder, set that as '777' recursively, and now everything works. Oh my god.
Thanks guys.